# Наличие только заданного элемента в списке

Tags: python, list, index

Есть список 1:

```
ind = [4, 9]
```

Есть список 2:

```
lvl = [[9], [3, 4, 6, 10], [4, 6], [], [1, 2, 7], [9], [6], [2], [], [9]]
```

Нужно взять только те индексы элементов lvl, в которых есть только элементы 4, 9, либо только 4, либо только 9. В данном случае нужно вывести `[0, 5, 9]`

Или **2 пример**
Список ind тот же, список lvl:

```
lvl = [[9], [3, 4, 6, 10], [4, 9], [4]]
```

Тут должно быть на выходе `[0, 2, 3]`

Comment: А в чем вопрос? циклом проходите по lvl и сравниваете как вам угодна элементы  lvl с ind, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Где попытки самостоятельного решения? Что не получается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(lvl) if v and not set(v) - set(ind)]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!